# What race is Brona?

Tags: shannara

Brona, aka the Warlock Lord, is the antagonist in several of the Shannara series of books. They always refer to him as the "Druid Brona", yet druid is a title and not a race. Is it ever mentioned anywhere what race he actually is?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the wiki entry](http://shannara.wikia.com/wiki/Warlock_Lord), he is currently a "spirit", but "His first attempt to subvert The Four Lands resulted in the First War of the Races, in which he led an army of Men." which suggests that he was initially human.

Comment: I'm not sure that suggests he was initially human. In the Second War of the Races, he subverted Trolls and Gnomes. One of the major themes throughout this series(at least that I've picked up on), is that humans are easily subverted(Trolls and Gnomes being descendants of humans from the Great Wars). Brona could easily have been a human, but he could have been a Dwarf as well.

Comment: True. But it's the closest I've found yet. He stored them up with talk of being the "pure" race. Could be a dodge though out even a direct reference to Hitler who want all that purebred himself.